# enableAjaxValidation is not working cactiveform in yii

Tags: yii

I am using both the client validation and ajax validation for my CActiveForm but both the client and ajax validations are not performing if i remove ajaxvalidation means to false the client validation is happening. can any suggest for the solution here i am posting my code

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'useraccess-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'enableAjaxValidation'=> true,
'clientOptions' => array(
    'validateOnSubmit' => true
),
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when tried to set id for feilds via htmlOptions
Check source code of generated page. Compare ids of fields in javascript code with ids in html code

Answer (score 0):

I am included JQuery twice. Need once and with framework.

```
 <?php Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```